# (Discord.JS) Bot not sending DM message when a user join

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots

For sending the DM Message, i use:

```js
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
    member.send('a');
});
```

I cannot understand what is wrong with this code so that the private message that should be sent is not being sent. Help-me, please!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you used **member.send** which is unnecessary and that's why the result is bad.

Use `message.author.send('your text here');`

Also, for the welcome code to work, this is my code:

`client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember => { let welcome = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Verified'); guildMember.roles.add(welcome); guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('welcome channel id').send(Welcome <@${guildMember.user.id}> to my server! Make sure to check the rules channel!`);
})

Also, replace client with bot. I named it differently.

Hope this helps!